# Explain MATLAB function smooth(x,y,span,'moving')

Tags: matlab, smoothing

I recently came across the Matlab smooth function used as follows:

```
ans = smooth(x, y, span, 'moving');
```

The Matlab documentation states

> yy = smooth(x,y,...) additionally specifies x data. If x is not provided, methods that require x data assume x = 1:length(y). You should specify x data when it is not uniformly spaced or sorted. If x is not uniform and you do not specify method, lowess is used. If the smoothing method requires x to be sorted, the sorting occurs automatically.

However, I am unclear as to what this actually means for the 'moving' average case.  Is x an index for the y data, and if so how do non-integer values of x affect the 'moving' average of y?

Answer (score 0):

Moving average means each value of the `yy` (or `ans` in your case) is an average of the n closest points. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average
There are several methods to calculate it - it depends on WHICH POINTS we will use. For example:

```
( (i-1) + (i-2) + ... + (i-n) )/n;
```

where n - is a `span` or *linear filtration level*.
This mean that first three points can't be calculated (there are no data for it). And sometimes result must be shifted (because really - average of the first 4 points not really corresponds to 4th elements).

So Matlab use another method:

```
yy(1) = y(1)
yy(2) = (y(1) + y(2) + y(3))/3
yy(3) = (y(1) + y(2) + y(3) + y(4) + y(5))/5
yy(4) = (y(2) + y(3) + y(4) + y(5) + y(6))/5
...
```

It's more useful.

About `x` and `y` - it is usual 2d-data: each `x` corresponds to each `y`. you can avoid setting of `x`, then matlab will use `[1, 2, 3, ..., length(y)]` sequence for this. But if you have some non-uniformly distributed data you have to set it for getting right result. So if you have non-integer values it will works correct, scaling it for x axis. Here the easiest example from my head: [image]

Comment: To make sure I understand you: Non-integer x'es with a moving average are just used for ordering, and the resulting smoothed y is the same as if you projected the order onto an integer index?

Comment: Sry, I don't understand what is 'non-integer progrcted onto an integer index', but look at my plot - points of resulted smoothed function (red) has the same non-integer x values as the used data (blue). 
Thats mean `smooth` takes into consideration different length between points for x-axis, but resulted points will not have integer x values but same as x-data you route into `smooth`.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have data **y** corrupted by noise and let's assume **y** = `[2.1, 3.2, 1.7, 4.5, 5.8, 6.9]`. Let's say that you have decided to use moving average of 3 window filter to smooth **y**.

```
smoothedY1 = (2.1 + 3.2 + 1.7)/3 = 2.3333
smoothedY2 = (3.2 + 1.7 + 4.5)/3 = 3.1333
smoothedY3 = (1.7 + 4.5 + 5.8)/3 = 4.0000
smoothedY3 = (4.5 + 5.8 + 6.9)/3 = 5.7333
```

Pay attention to the way corrupted data is being shifted to the left by one element per iteration. Now let's use `smooth()` in Matlab.

```
y = [2.1, 3.2, 1.7, 4.5, 5.8, 6.9];
smooth(y, 3, 'moving')
```

The above script yields the following result

```
ans =
    2.1000
    2.3333 <----
    3.1333      |  (smoothed data)
    4.0000      | 
    5.7333 <----
    6.9000
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your original question, the "x" data is just used for sorting, but is otherwise ignored when the method is 'moving':

```
>> x = rand(10, 1);
>> y = (1:10)' + 0.1*randn(10,1);
>> isequal(smooth(x,y,'moving'), smooth(y,'moving'))
ans =
   0
>> z = sortrows([x y], 1);
>> isequal(smooth(z(:,1),z(:,2),'moving'), smooth(z(:,2),'moving'))
ans =
   1
```

The "x" values aren't actually taken into account for the averaging, they are just used to sort "y" by increasing index.